# How can I get the correct line from grep?

Tags: linux, bash

This is my first question here. I've been practicing with Bash scripts at school, and I encountered a problem. Here i have a file and i have to extract the line where i *grep* the first parameter. However i always get the first line.

```
name_tofind=$1
exec < rubrica.txt
count=0
while read line; do
    if `grep -q $1`; then
        IFS=':'
        array=( $line )
        echo "Name:$1 Email:${array[1]} Address:${array[2]} Number:${array[3]}"
    else
        let "count++"
    fi
done    

if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "NOT FOUND"
fi
```

what should i add? I though about head|tail but i can't figure out how to use them correctly.

Comment: What does your input file look like and what kind of information are you looking for? It seems to me you don't even need a loop for this, a simple `grep` can get what you want.

Comment: I got rubrica.txt and it's structured this way: Name:Email:Address:TelephoneNumber. I want to get an array that has the correct line that has the name i searched

Comment: **EDIT** i deleted the while, seemed useless on second thought. The only thing i need is to extract the line that contains `$1`

Comment: "I want to get an array that has the correct line that has the name i searched " `IFS=: a=($(grep "$1" rubrica.txt))` ?

Comment: perhaps with an `-m1` to the `grep` to make sure it returns max one line.

Comment: i tried `array=( $( grep -m1 "$1" ) )` but it doesn't work. The output is blank except for the `$1` and the strings, of course. **EDIT** do i need the file? 'Cause with `exec` that should be settled.

Comment: **Edit 2** Whoops, that was the problem. I added rubrica.txt to the command and BOOM it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: since the grep is executed in a subshell there, while sharing your scripts STDIN and STDOUT, it does not inherit the redirections.

Comment: @Sam how do I close a question?

Comment: you don't normally close questions, keeping them public as long as people show interest in them is kind of the whole idea. i can post my solution as an answer and you can accept if you want. or you can do it yourself.